# Mybatis- Invalid bound statement (not found):

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, rest-assured

I have created a new API automation code with Cucumber framework using mybatis to connect to a MySQL database. This is my second project using mybatis so I am familiar with it but am getting the following error when I call the save method:

Error I am getting in line of feature file-

```
 When User retrieves data from DB using identifier "<apiIdentifier>"
  | db_expected_obj      |
```

```
Then the response code should be 200                                                            # com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.stepdefs.CommonStepDefs.verify_response_code_is_something(int)
  When User retrieves data from DB using identifier "v1quotequalifiergetall"                      # com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.stepdefs.DBStepDefs.user_retrieves_data_from_db_using_identifier_something(java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
    | db_expected_obj |
      org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.mapper.QuoteQualifierMapper.getAllQuoteQualifier
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:235)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.lambda$cachedInvoker$0(MapperProxy.java:108)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.apache.ibatis.util.MapUtil.computeIfAbsent(MapUtil.java:35)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedInvoker(MapperProxy.java:95)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy85.getAllQuoteQualifier(Unknown Source)
    at com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.DBBatis.v1quotequalifiergetallExpected(DBBatis.java:74)
    at com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.stepdefs.DBStepDefs.user_retrieves_data_from_db_using_identifier_something(DBStepDefs.java:61)
    at ✽.User retrieves data from DB using identifier "v1quotequalifiergetall"(file:///C:/Central_Apgl/tp_central_apgl/testAutomation/src/test/resources/features/quotequalifier.feature:9)
```

Feature file-

```
@v1 @Quotequalifier @getall @positive @testing
  Scenario Outline: 01 Get Quotequalifier Info with "<case>"
    Given a request with standard headers
    When the user sends a GET request to the endpoint "<endpoint>"
      | api_response_body | items |
    Then the response code should be 200
   When User retrieves data from DB using identifier "<apiIdentifier>"
  | db_expected_obj      |
#  Then Compare two stored variables
  #    | api_response_body | db_expected_obj |
  #  And Verify meta info using identifier "<apiIdentifier>"

    Examples: 
      | case                                                                  | apiIdentifier          | endpoint                                                                                                                     |
     # | positive case - Filter by quoteQualifierId                            | v1quotequalifiergetall | /apglmanager/api/v1/quoteQualifiers?limit=10&quoteQualifierId={{items[1].id}}                                           |
       #| positive case - Filter by quoteQualifierName                          | v1quotequalifiergetall | /apglmanager/api/v1/quoteQualifiers?limit=10&quoteQualifierName={{items[1].name}}                                 |
       #| positive case - Filter by quoteQualifier with special character       | v1quotequalifiergetall | /apglmanager/api/v1/quoteQualifiers?limit=10&quoteQualifier={{items[1].quoteQualifier}}                                |
       #| positive case - Filter by quoteQualifier with partial match           | v1quotequalifiergetall | /apglmanager/api/v1/quoteQualifiers?limit=10&quoteQualifier=like|'                                             |
       #| positive case - Offset by 2                                           | v1quotequalifiergetall | /apglmanager/api/v1/quoteQualifiers?limit=1&offset=0&quoteQualifierId={{items[3].id}}                        |
```

Step definition file-other common step definition file is working

dbstep definition file

```
package com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.stepdefs;

import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.DBBatis;
import com.tangoe.cucumberbot.api.ApiDataUtil;
import com.tangoe.cucumberbot.api.TestDataUtil;

import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.testng.Assert;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DBStepDefs {

    @Autowired
    private ApiDataUtil apiDataUtil;

    @Autowired
    private TestDataUtil testDataUtil;

    @Autowired
    private DBBatis dBBatis;

    @And("^User retrieves data from DB using identifier \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_retrieves_data_from_db_using_identifier_something(String identifier, List<String> details)
            throws Throwable {
        String saveRecordsInKey = details.get(0);
        String getResponseKey = null;
        if (details.size() > 1) {
            getResponseKey = details.get(1);
        }
        HashMap<String, Object> saveMap = new HashMap<>();

        if (identifier.equals("v2currenciesgetall")) {
            /*List<Map<String, Object>> currencies = dBBatis.v2getAllCurrencyExpected();
            saveMap.put(saveRecordsInKey, currencies);*/
        } else if (identifier.equals("v2currenciesget")) {
            /*Map<String, Object> currency = dBBatis.v2getAllCurrencyByIdExpected();
            saveMap.put(saveRecordsInKey, currency);*/
        } else if (identifier.equals("v2countriesgetall")) {
            /*List<Map<String, Object>> countries = dBBatis.v2getAllCountryExpected();
            saveMap.put(saveRecordsInKey, countries);*/
        } else if (identifier.equals("v2countriesget")) {
            /*Map<String, Object> country = dBBatis.v2getAllCountryByIdExpected();
            saveMap.put(saveRecordsInKey, country);*/
        } else if (identifier.equals("v2vendorsgetall")) {
            /*List<Map<String, Object>> countries = dBBatis.v2getAllVendorExpected();
            saveMap.put(saveRecordsInKey, countries);*/
        } else if (identifier.equals("v2getDeliveryMethodsByIdget")) {
                /*Map<String, Object> deliveryMethod = dBBatis.v2getDeliveryMethodsByIdExpected();
                saveMap.put(saveRecordsInKey, deliveryMethod);*/
            }
        else if (identifier.equals("v1quotequalifiergetall")) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> countries = dBBatis.v1quotequalifiergetallExpected();
        saveMap.put(saveRecordsInKey, countries);
        }
        
         
        apiDataUtil.setScenarioData(saveMap);
    }
```

Mybatis file-

```
package com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.filter.CostCenterFilter;
import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.filter.QuoteQualifierFilter;
import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.mapper.QuoteQualifierMapper;
import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.mapper.CostCenterMapper;
import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.mapper.TenantMapper;
import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.pojo.Tenant;
import com.tangoe.cucumberbot.api.TestDataUtil;
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.tangoe.cucumberbot.api.ApiDataUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class DBBatis {
    
    @Autowired
    private CostCenterMapper costCenterMapper;

    @Autowired
    private TenantMapper tenantMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    private QuoteQualifierMapper quoteQualifierMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApiDataUtil apiDataUtil;
    
    private CostCenterFilter getCostCenterFilter() {
        CostCenterFilter costCenterFilter = new CostCenterFilter();
        return costCenterFilter;
    }
    
    public Long getCostCenterCount() {
        return costCenterMapper.getAllCostCenterCount(getCostCenterFilter());
    }
    
    /*private QuoteQualifierFilter getQuoteQualifierFilter() {
        QuoteQualifierFilter QuoteQualifierFilter = new QuoteQualifierFilter();
        return QuoteQualifierFilter;
    }*/
    
    public Long getQuoteQualifierCount() {
        return quoteQualifierMapper.getAllQuoteQualifierCount(getQuoteQualifierFilter());
    }
    
    /// quote qualifier
    
    private QuoteQualifierFilter getQuoteQualifierFilter() {
        QuoteQualifierFilter quoteQualifierFilter = new QuoteQualifierFilter();
        HashMap<String, String> paramsMap = quoteQualifierFilter.getParamsFromEndpoint(apiDataUtil.getEndPoint());
        
        if(paramsMap.containsKey("quoteQualifierId")) {
            quoteQualifierFilter.setquoteQualifierId(Long.parseLong(paramsMap.get("quoteQualifierId")));
        }
        if(paramsMap.containsKey("name")) {
            quoteQualifierFilter.setName(paramsMap.get("name"));
        }

        return quoteQualifierFilter;
    }
    
    public List<Map<String, Object>> v1quotequalifiergetallExpected() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Map<String, Object>> quotequalifier = mapper.convertValue(quoteQualifierMapper.getAllQuoteQualifier(getQuoteQualifierFilter() ), new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});
        return quotequalifier;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> insertTenantRecords(DataTable dataTable) {

        List<List<String>> dataToCreate = dataTable.asLists();

        List<Map<String, Object>> createdData = new ArrayList<>();
        for(List<String> eachRow : dataToCreate) {
            String randomNumber = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(6);
            Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
            tenant.setShortName(eachRow.get(0)+randomNumber);
            tenant.setName(eachRow.get(1)+randomNumber);
            tenant.setUpperName(eachRow.get(2)+randomNumber);
            tenant.setStatus(eachRow.get(3));
            tenantMapper.insertTenant(tenant);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, Object> createdTenant = mapper.convertValue(tenant, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
            createdTenant.put(TestDataUtil.dataCreatedFlagName, true);
            createdTenant.put(TestDataUtil.testDataFlagName, true);
            createdData.add(createdTenant);
        }

        return createdData;
    }
}
```

mapper xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.mapper.QuoteQualifierMapper">

    <resultMap id="quoteQualifierResultMap" type="com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.pojo.QuoteQualifier">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <result property="quoteQualifier" column="quote_qualifier"/>
        <result property="created" column="created"/>
        <result property="createdBy" column="created_by"/>
    </resultMap>
    
    <select id="getAllQuoteQualifier" resultMap="quoteQualifierResultMap" parameterType="com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.filter.QuoteQualifierFilter">
        SELECT id, name, quoteQualifier, created, createdBy
        FROM quote_qualifier
    </select>
    
</mapper>
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tangoe</groupId>
    <artifactId>apglapiautomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>apglapiautomation</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tangoe</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumberbot</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.18</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>timestamp-property</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>build.time</name>
                            <pattern>dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss</pattern>
                            <locale>en_US</locale>
                            <timeZone>IST</timeZone>
                            <!-- timeZone>EST5EDT</timeZone-->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>com.tangoe.cucumberbot.listeners.SuitesSummaryReport</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>${testSuite}</suiteXmlFiles>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

mapper interface file

```
package com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.mapper;

import java.util.List;

import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.filter.QuoteQualifierFilter;
import com.tangoe.apglapiautomation.db.pojo.QuoteQualifier;

public interface QuoteQualifierMapper {
    
    List<QuoteQualifier> getAllQuoteQualifier(QuoteQualifierFilter quoteQualifierFilter);
    
    QuoteQualifier getAllQuoteQualifierById(Long quoteQualifierId);
    
    Long getAllQuoteQualifierCount(QuoteQualifierFilter quoteQualifierFilter);
}
```

mybatis config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mappersss/QuoteQualifierMapper.xml" />
        </mappers>
</configura
```

I want to run  line of feature file code

Comment: Your MyBatis config XML contains obvious error (`mappersss`), however, as you are using Spring Boot, you should let [mybatis-spring-boot](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/index.html) detect mappers. Please read the linked doc. If you are doing something complex, you should read the [mybatis-spring](https://mybatis.org/spring/) doc, too.